# Casting String to Int in Cloud Firestore Security Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am [coming from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48795711/6509751). I thought about starting a bounty on it because it has not received any attention in months and over the time I did not see any answers, but I think that my desire is a bit different.

If there is a number as a field of a document, but specified as a `string`:

[image: screenshot]

A problem with [Firestore Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) arises.

Checks like this become impossible:

```
resource.data.number > 11
```

It is **not possible** to compare *strings* as if they were *ints*.

The *simulator* exception is as follows:

```
Unsupported operation error. Received: string > int. Expected: constraint > constraint, int > int, float > float, duration > duration, timestamp > timestamp, constraint > any, any > constraint.
```

*Is there a way to convert my operation to `int > int`?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Integer) that shows you how to convert strings to integers in the Firestore rules docs.

```
int("2") == 2
int(2.0) == 2
```

So your check could be:

```
int(resource.data.number) > 11
```

Comment: This actually made me use `string()` etc. as well to have type-safe operations :)